# background images showing on chrome but no other browser

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I have an issue where my background image shows just on Chrome but not on Firefox or Edge.

What I'm trying to do is to have a different background image every time I load my page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalBGs = 5;
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalBGs);
  
  $(".main").css({
    backgroundImage: "url(../img/img_" + rnd + ".jpg)"
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  background-image: url("../img/img_0.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Try clearing the cache in Chrome, and see if it still works (in Chrome). If not then your images may have a path problem. ... Alternatively, and if clearing the cache is not ideal, affix something random to the end of the `.jpg` part, like `.jpg?21` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Images shows on Crome even after clearing cashe out. after adding random stuff to file name image doesn't show on Chrome. This stuff does my head. Can find solution for Edge and FF

Comment: I think it might be something wrong with my file path. Tried to copy all images next to Index.html and changed file path just to img/img_0.jpg and it works. Will play around with file path tomorrow and see how it goes

Comment: I created a simple demo and executed these code correctly. But I'm not sure how you stored these resource files and its structures, so I think the file paths you mentioned are possible.

Comment: It must be file paths. I have project folder which contains index.html, css folder, js folder and img folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you everyone who tried to help, but I've just had moment of enlightenment and solved this problem. still don't know answer why it was working on Chrome, but managed to make it work properly on other browsers now.
What i did:

1. Added "style="background-image: url(''); " as inline style on my html object.
2. Changed url on js function to = img/img_" + rnd + ".jpg . Because it goes from html file. My previous url basically was looking for imgages outside of project folder.

Again, thanks everyone who tried to help.